# HttpWebRequest not getting the response body correctly

Tags: c#

I have the following code that connects to a webservice, sends a POST request and the service returns a JPG image:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myservice);
var postData = string.Concat(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(mykey), "=", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(myvalue));
var postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

// Submit the POST data
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
}

using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result);

    var f = Path.GetTempFileName();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(f, b);
}
```

I've tests the form values using `Postman` and the service successfully returns the image and it is correctly displayed.

However when I use the code above and rename the file to `jpg` the file is not a valid image. I can't figure out why the above is not working.

The server is return the image correctly. `Content-Type` is set to `image/jpeg` and `Content-Length` is set to eg, 70000. But when I save the content to a file, the size doubles.

Note:
I can't use `HttpClient` because I need to use this code as a CLR function with SQL Server.

Comment: Have you tried  stream.CopyTo(file); ?

Comment: Why are you reading the response as a string and then ASCII-decoding it if it's supposed to be an image?

Comment: @madreflection I've tried using `WriteAllText` and the output is always the same. Never a valid image.

Comment: Why `WriteAllText`? An image is not text.

Comment: Just take the `result` bytes and write that using `File.WriteAllBytes(f, result);`. Side note: `HttpWebRequest` is deprecated, you should use `HttpClient` instead. SQL Server does support this on all supported versions, as it uses .Net 4+

Comment: @Charlieface Writing to file is for testing purposes. I return SqlBytes from the method. I needed to test the method outside of CLR. When I implemented the method with `HttpClient` I got errors trying to add `System.Net.Http` as an assembly.

Comment: Side note: making a web call directly from SQL Server via SQLCLR is almost universally a bad idea. Use a Powershell or Python or C# application instead.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `StreamReader` to `MemoryStream` and this the final working CLR function:

```
[SqlFunction]
public static SqlBytes GetImageFromService(SqlString url, SqlString data)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url.Value);
    var postData = string.Concat(WebUtility.UrlEncode("imageToEncode"), "=", WebUtility.UrlEncode(data.Value));
    var postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
    }

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(stream);
        var bytes = stream.ToArray();

        return new SqlBytes(bytes);
    }
}
```